# Not sure how to start an element off as transparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am trying to make an unordered list fade in upon the click of the main header, but I am not sure as to how to have the unordered list begin as transparent. I don't want to fade it out as that involves an animation. I just want it to be invisible when the page is loaded.

EX:

HTML

```
<h1 id="event">Click Me To Show List</h1>
<ul id="list">
    <li>Example 1</li>
    <li>Example 2</li>
</ul>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // How would I make the <ul> start as transparent ???

    $('#event').click(function(){
        $('#list').fadeIn(3000);
    });

});
```

Comment: Note: you are missing a `.` between `$('#list')` and `fadeIn(3000)`

Comment: Should the list reserve its space in the document or not ?

Comment: @empiric If I wanted it to reserve it's space, how would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have an error in your statement. It is:

```
$('#list').fadeIn(3000);
// -------^ You forgot the .
```

Use `opacity: 0;` to make it transparent in CSS. Or if you wanna use jQuery, use [`$.fadeTo()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) this way:

```
$(elem).fadeTo(0, 0);
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("div").fadeTo(0, 0).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden {opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus error reiciendis, numquam id, praesentium illum. Enim molestias modi facilis pariatur eligendi doloribus qui assumenda voluptates, ut, nobis vel consequatur dolorem.</div>
```

And if you wanna `fadeIn()` the element, you can start with `.hide()` and then `fadeIn()`, by using a `.hidden` class like this. You won't see the flash of the content, whatsoever!

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("div").hide().removeClass("hidden").fadeIn(3000);
});
```

```css
.hidden {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus error reiciendis, numquam id, praesentium illum. Enim molestias modi facilis pariatur eligendi doloribus qui assumenda voluptates, ut, nobis vel consequatur dolorem.</div>
```

Comment: Why not just `hide()`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That hides, removes from the view!

Comment: @PraveenKumar, You sure about hide-"removes from the view" ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar that's right, although the OP doesn't state that that is a problem. Event then `display: none` is a better solution.

Comment: @Manoz *unordered list begin as transparent*. That's why I gave this solution. May be I am wrong!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan See my second snippet!

Comment: This worked. One more question though. I am new to JQuery. I am using JQuery verison 2.1.4. I see you are using 1.9.1. Any benefits to one over the other?

Comment: Well, I trust the older one, spec. `1.9.1` so much as there is a major release with 1.10.x by removing IE support and blah blah!

Comment: Your answer worked, but the answer given by @empiric achieved the same result in a more simple manner. Thank you for helping me though!

Comment: @SkyyCP Did you forget my second snippet?

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```css
#list {
  display: none;
}
```

to your css.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xroL6p13/)**

If you want it to do with jQuery, you can add the follwing inside the `.ready`-handler:

```
$('#list').hide();
```

Comment: *unordered list begin as transparent*, not *not in the view*.

Comment: I just want it to be invisible when the page is loaded

Comment: Yes indeed opacity would be a solution here from what OP requested. But I was reffering to the `fadeIn()`. Which will not work with `visibility` or `opacity`. It now depends on wether the space in the document should be reserved or not.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I guess you are right now that I'm paying attention. I will remark you as the correct answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<h1 id="event">Click Me To Show List</h1>
<ul id="list" style="display:none;">
    <li>Example 1</li>
    <li>Example 2</li>
</ul>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // How would I make the <ul> start as transparent ???

    $('#event').click(function(){
        $('#list').show();
    });

});
```

Comment: I'm guessing because he mentioned transparency, which would mean toggling the opacity.  Was difficult to tell from the question.  Do you know why your comment is vague and unhelpful?

Comment: I'm sorry that you're so miserable.  I hope you cheer up.